# Goodness of fit between actual values and non-linear model

Tags: model-selection, goodness-of-fit, r-squared

I was wanting to get a goodness of fit similar to R^2 for a model I'm evaluating.  The output of the model is one of 8 numbers based on environmental characteristics.  This is not a linear model, so TSS<>RSS+ESS.  Trying to compute R^2 results in a negative number sometimes - R^2 is intended for linear models.  Any thoughts of the best way to get a statistic for this?  I can do mean absolute deviation to compare two different models, or take the deviation and square it (essentially RSS), but that mostly just tells me if a model is better or worse than another one, not necessarily "good" or "bad."  With an R^2 of .75 for my purposes I can say that the fit of one model is pretty good.  Is there a better statistic than R^2 (or adjusted R^2 - they suffer from the same problem) I can get where I just have actual values and the predicted values and make an evaluation based on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options, but none of them give an "absolute truth" result between 0 and 1. 
The two common options are AIC and BIC. see here:
[Model selection with nonlinear fitting? Statistical tests seem ambiguous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46098/model-selection-with-nonlinear-fitting-statistical-tests-seem-ambiguous)

Another option is the S measure:
http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/regression-analysis-how-to-interpret-s-the-standard-error-of-the-regression

Some thoughts:

1. As models become more complex, there are less "absolute truth" answers like R^2 between 0 and 1. With more flexible models, it's easy to get to a 100% fit of training data, and metrics like R^2 are irrelevant.
2. Make sure you test your model with some test data. non linear models tend to overfit.

Comment: So, I don't really have a model to work with - I just have two vectors of values that are provided to me, so I can't really compute the likelihood function or anything, so AIC and BIC are probably a bit tricky.  I was having trouble finding a great solution.  It sounds like there are a few different options, but that there is not necessarily a standard, great way to approach it.

Comment: Not that I'm familiar with, but maybe other people can help. By the way, if you got a negative R^2, you probably have a bug somewhere...

Comment: Instead of trying to evaluate how good is your model, try to evaluate different models on a test set. This way you'll be able to see which model predicts an unknown sample in a better way. Especially if your task is prediction.